# mod_rewrite /foo to /index.php?id=foo AND /foo/foo2 to /index.php?id=foo/foo2

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory, clean-urls

I have a problem with mod_rewrite.

I want to redirect those URIs in the title. I use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(folders not to be redirected e.g. css|images)
RewriteCond $1 !^(.*).(file extension e.g. png|css|txt|php)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It work only if I put all the resources in a folder, else it would tell me:

```
"/foo/index.php" not found.
```

So to solve that I put all the resources in the folder "www"

But when I try to load the resources from a subfolder of e.g. "foo" it tells me:

```
The requested URL "/foo/foo2" was not found on this server.
```

How can I load resources from a subfolder like "/foo/foo2" or even "/foo/foo2/foo3"?

And how can I solve the problem with the automatic search for index.php in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the following to achieve your desired result. It doesn't filter by file extension, but rather checks to see if the file actually exists. One thing that is a little different is that it first appends a trailing slash to your links, something you may not want.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# This appends a trailing slash. You will have to update http://so with your domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://so/$1/ [L,R=301]

# This does the internal redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If you don't want the tailing slashes, you could use the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You're right. I don't want to have those ugly trailing slashes appending at the end. But how to remove them or rewrite without them?

Comment: @JuliusRickert, I've added another option without the trailing slashes.

Comment: I think "[NC]" is not needed but a "[L]" must be there. Am I right?

Comment: `[NC]` refers to case-insensitive. `[L]` refers to the last rule to be applied if true. You could add `[L,NC]` but I wouldn't recommend changing it to `[L]`. Did my second suggestion work for you? If so, please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow. Yes if it works, of course. :) One question: Is RewriteBase nessesary? The .htaccess is in root folder.